# redirect a localhost web service to https by nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect a web service fossil-scm by secure nginx. But I don't know what's the proper settings and how to check the error log.

I wish through this setting I could use

```
https://test.example.com/fossil/a/b/c
```

instead of

```
http://test.example.com:8888/a/b/c
```

The error message shows 'page not found'.

Here is my nginx setting file.

```
upstream fossil_server {
  server localhost:8888 fail_timeout=0
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 default ssl;
  server_name test.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;               
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;                          
  ssl_ciphers 'AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';                  
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;                                  
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;                                
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;           
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;                                 
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;                       
  location / {
    ...
  }
  location ^~ /fossil/ {
    proxy_pass http://fossil_server;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current configuration is mapping `https://test.example.com/fossil/a/b/c` to the upstream `/fossil/a/b/c`. In order to strip off the leading `/fossil` you need to add a trailing `/`. Try:

```
location ^~ /fossil/ {
    proxy_pass http://fossil_server/;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: This work on the first page and the page contains a form for login, I've checked the html source, the form's url is `http://fossil_server/login`.  When I pressed my user name and password, and the next page will show ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. The browser new URL  changed to `http://fossil_server/login`.

Comment: I found this should setup fossil by --base-url option, too. ref: https://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg15757.html